# monitoring internet activity?

Tags: c#

hi  i am working on a window application using c#, 
i want to know that how to monitor computer activity by internet activity or website..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to check out 'packet sniffing' tools, for example [Ethereal](http://www.ethereal.com/) or [TCPDump](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tcpdump) - they are open source and have command-line interfaces, so you may be able to call those from your program and analyse any log files it may produce. Packet sniffers scan your network for packets being sent around, internet activity will typically invlve TCP and IP packets so you could filter for those and look at where they have been sent from / where they are going to.

Comment: Uh, we changed the name of Ethereal to Wireshark (http://www.wireshark.org) back in 2006...

Comment: @Gerald: So who is at www.ethereal.com?

Answer (score 3):

you can use sharpPcap, it's a packet capture framework for .Net
the library has a lot of useful functions for monitoring packets,
you can filter HTTP packets.

Answer (score 2):

I would say that you should have a look at the System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter class. [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.performancecounter.aspx) for that class.

Here is a little code snippet that fetches the bytes per second on the network interface.

```
PerformanceCounterCategory category = new PerformanceCounterCategory("Network Interface");

// Look at GetInstanceNames() result to find you interface,  mine's 3 for example
string instance = category.GetInstanceNames()[0];

PerformanceCounter sent = new PerformanceCounter("Network Interface", "Bytes Sent/sec", instance);
PerformanceCounter received = new PerformanceCounter("Network Interface", "Bytes Received/sec", instance);

while (true)
{
     Console.WriteLine("Send {0}b/s\tReceive {1}b/s", sent.NextValue(), received.NextValue());
     Thread.Sleep(500);
}
```